# Clips Family Expert System

Tags: clips, expert-system, family-tree

I'm trying to implement a basic expert system in the Clips programming language. I have a knowledge base of children with their respective parents. I want to set up a rule so that if two children have the same parents then it asserts the fact that they are siblings.

---

```
(deftemplate person "family tree"
          (slot name)
          (slot father)
          (slot mother))

(assert
        (person
                (name "William")
                (father "John")
                (mother "Megan")))
(assert
        (person (name "David")
                (father "John")
                (mother "Megan")))

(defrule sibling
        (person
                (name ?name1)
                (father ?x)
                (mother ?x))
        (person
                (name ?name2)
                (father ?y)
                (mother ?y)))
```

and when I define the rule I get a syntax error:

```
Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for defrule.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for your rule is:

```
(defrule sibling 
   (person (name ?name1) (father ?x) (mother ?x)) 
   (person (name ?name2) (father ?y) (mother ?y)) 
   => 
   ...)
```

Within a `rule`, a `template` is referred as:

```
(template_name (slot_name value) (slot_name value))
```

A rule is divided in two sides: the LHS (Left-Hand Side) where you define the conditions satisfying such rule and the RHS (Right-Hand Side) where you define the consequent actions.

In CLIPS, the `=>` operator separates the two sides.

Example:

```
(defrule animal-is-a-duck
    (animal ?name)
    (quacks)
    (two legs)
    (lay eggs)
    =>
    (assert (animal ?name is a duck)))
```

You can read more about CLIPS syntax in the [basic programming guide](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v630/bpg.pdf).

Comment: Thanks that worked but I had to put MAIN:: in front of my sibling title. But now when I call the rule in an `assert` I keep getting errors. I've tried syntax  `(assert MAIN::sibling (person (name "First_Person")) (person (name "Second_Person")))`  and `(assert (MAIN::sibling (person ("David")) (person ("William"))))` I've also tried without the MAIN:: Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question specifying what errors you get. Also write deftemplates, facts and rules separating each statement with a newline which helps readability a lot.

Comment: Sorry but I had to unaccept the answer. The rule actually didn't go through. I'm getting a syntax error now. I editted the question to show my code and my error.

Comment: Edited the aswer.

Comment: so my RHS would look something like `(assert (person (?name1)) is siblings with (person (?name2)))` correct?

Comment: The `assert` statement allows you to introduce more knowledge into the CLIPS engine in form of facts. You cannot assert a fact like that. Rather something like: `(assert (?name1 is siblings with ?name2))` or `(assert (siblings (first ?name1) (second ?name2)))` depending whether you want to use an Ordered or a Template fact.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule should be something like this:

```
    (defrule sibling 
        (person
                (name ?name1)
                (father ?x)
                (mother ?y))
        (person
                (name ?name2)
                (father ?x)
                (mother ?y))
        (test (neq ?name1 ?name2))
    =>
    (assert (siblings ?name1 ?name2)))
```

The original rule could be satisfied only if the father and the mother were the same person in each fact being matched.

This rule permits duplicates:

```
    f-3     (siblings "David" "William")
    f-4     (siblings "William" "David")
```

so you can either catch that in another rule or you can write a more complex rule (or another rule) also matching against currently generated matched siblings facts.